# Vue & Jest. Test method was called when child component emits event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

So following the `setMethods` being deprecated in Vue-test-utils, I'm changing my tests to use `jest.spyOn`. I simply want to emit an event from a child component and check the corresponding method was called on the parent, but somehow my method never gets called.

```js
it('calls promptPasswordReset method when forgotten-password event is emitted from LoginForm', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(login, { store, localVue })
    const promptPasswordResetSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'promptPasswordReset')
    wrapper.findComponent(LoginForm).vm.$emit('forgotten-password')
    expect(promptPasswordResetSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

The corresponding child template:

```html
<login-form
    @login="login"
    @sign-up="isSignUpModalActive = true"
    @forgotten-password="promptPasswordReset"
>
</login-form>
```

I don't understand because the event is properly emitted when I check `wrapper.emitted` and spyOn works because if I manually trigger the method, it is called!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To spy on a component's methods, use `jest.spyOn()` on the component's *`methods` definition*, and *then mount*:

```js
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'

//...                                                   
const promptPasswordResetSpy = jest.spyOn(MyComponent.methods, 'promptPasswordReset')
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, /*...*/)
wrapper.findComponent(LoginForm).vm.$emit('forgotten-password')
expect(promptPasswordResetSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```